# Screen brightness changes on reboot

Tags: nvidia

I have Dell Vostro 1720 with nvidia graphics card. On reboot, screen brightness changes seemingly randomly. For example, if I set brightness to 70%, after reboot it's usually ~47%, sometimes 100%. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

That one worked to me in ubuntu 12.04

**edit /etc/rc.local to insert your preffered value:**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

add the following :

```
  sleep 1
    chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
    chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness
    chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
    echo X >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
    echo 1 >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
    echo 1 >/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness
```

X=191 adjust maximun brightness to me

**This will work like a charm** !